# How to run python script in linux without root?

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver

I want to run a python script on Linux. using selenium.

I'm getting an error and apparently it's caused by running with root privileges.

How to run python script in linux without root?

Error: Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed

*A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

My code:

```
    op = Options()
    op.add_argument('headless')
    chromedriver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=op)
    url = '.......'
```

try: op.add_argument('headless'), but not solved. also others..

```
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Most Python scripts do not require root permissions, neither does Selenium. The issue is somewhere else

Comment: ...I mean, in general, your process isn't root unless you go out of your way to _make_ it root, so the answer is usually "stop doing that" for whatever value of "that" is the mechanism you're using to escalate privileges. If you're starting your process from a systemd service, create a dedicated user and set `User=` in the service definition. If you're starting your process by ssh'ing in as root, create a different account and ssh as that new user. If you're running in Docker, use the `USER` directive; etc -- figuring out what to change _for you_ requires information you aren't giving us.

Comment: (because we don't need to know what's _in_ your Python code; instead, we need to know _how you're starting_ your Python code, because that's what determines the user account your code is run under -- though really, since it's not a problem with the contents of the code, I'm not sure it's on-topic here at all -- [unix.se] is more appropriate for figuring out how to set up user accounts, or configure which ones you're using).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I use digitalocean. I open the console after logging in: root@ubuntu... and then run the python script.

Comment: ...yeah, don't do that; create a non-root user. :)